# How to implement social "sign in with / login using" facebook, google, twitter in NativeScript?

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios, nativescript

Basically: How to implement social "sign in with / login using" facebook, google, twitter in NativeScript?

- Is there a module / plugin for this? Is it even possible?
- Can I use something like [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/index.html) to do this?

Comment: How is this question even "off-topic"? (this comment question might be off-topic too?... god, I think I just limbo'd this question)

Answer (score 2):

There is a module for Facebook, however, I haven't used it so I can't confirm it's usage. Just search on npmjs.com for 'nativescript' and you'll find it.

It is very possible to do anything you want with NativeScript, anything you can do in a native mobile app, you can pretty much do with NativeScript. It's just a matter of "HOW" not "IF" :)

As for *HybridAuth* if that is a complete server side solution, it would definitely work if you are sending info to your server and then bringing some data back down. If it uses anything DOM/web related then it's not the way to go since this is a native app and not a hybrid app.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: "anything you can do in a native mobile app, you can pretty much do with NativeScript", yeah I agree NativeScript is cool, and feels like the right way to go but with lacking examples, especially with native calls, it can be frustrating and discouraging

Comment: Check out my blog (http://bradmartin.net) for some sample code on making the native calls. I have several posts on how to do things for Android. I know there aren't a ton of examples, but the docs provide a good starting point. Also, if you have any questions, the forums are filled with great {N} developers who can provide good info. I prefer it over SO for NativeScript, you get a dedicated pool of devs and the core team will chime in from time to time with help.